# What does 「社会に向けて作品を問う」 mean?

Tags: translation, words

I am currently translating course descriptions in to English as part of my job, and I came across this expression in a description for an Art class which I found completely baffling. As far as I know, 「問う」means to ask, but to ask an art piece? What does this mean, and why is it said in this way? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Edit: My apologies, I should have included the original sentence. Here it is!

「芸術家は社会の中で創作活動を行い，社会に向けて作品を問う。」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 問う is not about asking a question, but about asking for a reputation/judgement from many people. What artists will get from the society is not answers but reputations.

According to [a dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154854/meaning/m0u/), 問う has the following meanings:

> - 多くの人に**判断**を求める。
> - 人の能力や物**事の価値**などを改めて試す。

Perhaps "to test" is the closest single-word equivalent in English.

Comment: What's the significance of contrasting 社会の中で vs. 社会に向けて in his phrase?

Comment: And as a related question: couldn't it mean that "artists are creators on one hand, but they are also passing judgments on (i.e. questioning) others' art to the society"? Something like: they are creators and public opinion-makers at the same time.

Comment: @macraf ①社会の中で問う is simply unnatural. While 社会 itself is emphasized, there is no contrast between 社会の中で and 社会に向けて. They create in the society, and they 問う to the society. ②Again, this 問う is not "to question." Artists don't make opinions nor criticize others in this context; they only *receive* opinions from the society after they create something.

Comment: 1) Why is 社会の中で here at all? 2) I implicitly asked for a reason. You responded with "again, because it is so". I can't say I've learnt the reason from your answer.

Comment: Because 社会との関わり is what the author wants to emphasize. The usage of 向けて itself is contrasted to nothing; it's the word that happens to be used with 問う. "It's in the society that artists create, and it's the society that artists ask for the value of their works." We say Aを社会に向けて問う and Aを社会に問う, but usually not Aを社会で問う.

Comment: 芸術家は創作活動を行い，社会に向けて作品を問う。 Meets these criteria too. I did not ask why is the second 社会に向けて used, I asked why the two phrases with 社会 are used together. And I still have no clue.

Comment: @macraf Saying 社会 twice in this way means 社会 is important in this sentence.  I feel the implication of this sentence is "Artists cannot exist without the society."

Comment: @macraf As naruto mentioned, "society" is mentioned twice intentionally to emphasize that artists can only exist within a society. Also, it seems that it is possible to say "の中で問う" but it seems to be a different use. It would not mean the same thing. Common uses for this use seem to be 「心の中で問う」「頭の中で問う」「自身の中で問う」.  Essentially, 「の中で問う」 is to "inquire from within", while 「に向けて問う」 is to "inquire towards". I simply did not recognize this specific use with art work, and to be honest I still find it awkward but it seems to be a standard phrase.

Answer (score 2):

This 問う means "ask a judgment". 芸術家は、社会に向けて作品を問う means "Artists ask a judgment about their art to society(people).

For example, Japanese politicians often say 選挙で民意を問いたい(I want to elicit the public opinion in election).